# My website changes its layout once I try to minify css

Tags: wordpress, themes

My website which is on Jkreativ theme(wordpress) changes its layout once i try to minify the css for performance issues . How can I get around this

Comment: You should provide proper pointers for this questions along with sample or the web url etc

Comment: My website is http://www.fraiche.net.in/Fraiche-Fresheners. Am using Jkreativ theme on wordpress .

Comment: Your site does not seem to be broken from anywhere it looks good to me. TO improve the performance have a look at my answer

Comment: No Shiv it's not broken right now because i reverted it removing the plugin which was doing the job of minifying the css

Comment: Got it. Please see the answer if that helps or checkout https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok . Thank You For the answer. I'll let you know if any of those plugins workout . Because i've used 2 plugins out of them and they've given me same problems

Answer (score 0):

From my work experience you dont need to do some special thing rather depend on certain plugins to help you out. Have a look at this post which talks about the fast Wordpress site and plugins that will help you achieve the same.

http://www.bloggingwizard.com/free-speed-enhancing-wordpress-plugins/

Comment: I tried all the plugins you asked me to. But no luck whatsoever. Whenever the things are minified the layout is totally gone

Comment: Hi Shiv Kumar . I tried all the steps you've suggested but I don't see any improvement in the page speed . It is still the same